# How get schema of a column in a dataframe (not all schema)?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

i have a dataframe after a flatten operation.

I want return to original dataframe.

for example:
Df:

```
 |-- delivery: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- load_delivery_intervals: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- from_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- to_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- delivery_start_date_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- delivery_end_date_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- duration: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- week_days: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- delivery_capacity_quantity: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- quantity_unit: string (nullable = true)
```

i have a dataframe (flatten) like:
flat_df_new:

```
delivery_from_time: string (nullable = true)
 delivery_to_time: string (nullable = true)
 delivery_delivery_start_date_time: string (nullable = true)
 delivery_delivery_end_date_time: string (nullable = true)
 delivery_duration: string (nullable = true)
 delivery_delivery_capacity_quantity: string (nullable = true)
 delivery_quantity_unit: string (nullable = true)
```

flat_df_new is flatten dataframe (explode all struct Type) and operation on it.

parentList are List of array struct exploded in df original.

```py
    for parent in parentList: 
        df_temp=df.select(parent).schema <--get struct Type schema 
        flat_df_new=flat_df_new.withColumn(parent,....) <--- here now i want add a column named as parent variable but with schema as df_temp and value as column in flat_df_new.
```

Thanks
Regards

Comment: just select that column first? like `df.select('delivery').printSchema()`

Comment: yes ok but now i want add a column to df1 like:
df is originale dataframe:
flat_df_new is flatten dataframe (esplode all struct Type) and operation on it:
parentList are List of array struct exploded in df original.
for parent in parentList:
            df_temp=df.select(parent).schema  <--get struct Type schema
            flat_df_new=flat_df_new.withColumn(parent,....) now i want add a column named as parent variable but with schema as df_temp and value as column in flat_df_new.